# Compact syntax for static Create() method on generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I have a pair of classes. These are literally copy/paste from my project:

```
public static class PageResult
{
    public static PageResult<T> Create<T>(int totalCount, IList<T> items)
    {
        return new PageResult<T>()
        {
            TotalCount = totalCount,
            Items = items,
        };
    }
}

public class PageResult<T>
{
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The reason I did this is so that I could use `PageResult.Create(5, listOf5Items)` as opposed to any other lengthier syntax. I didn't put the Create method in the `PageResult(T)` class because I'm pretty sure that requires me to type `PageResult<int>(5, listOf5Numbers)` instead, and that's an extra five characters...

But having two classes for it seems pretty lame. Is there a way I can get the more compact syntax without having a throwaway class just to store it?

Comment: If this is lame, a good chunk of the .NET base library is lame as well, because this pattern is used quite a bit and is in fact promoted in the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2004/03/15/89860.aspx) (older but still relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noted, you'd have to specify type parameters to even access the `Create` function, because that specific `PageResult<T>` class won't even exist until the JIT creates it when a method starts calling it. See [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) for an instance of the .NET Framework itself doing just this pattern for the basically the same reason.

Note that another option is to make the `PageResult` class non-`static`, and inherit `PageResult<T> : PageResult` which will allow you to store a collection of `PageResult` objects without a type parameter. This can also be useful if you use an `abstract PageResult`

Comment: Had no idea framework code did stuff the same way. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You could potentially make a VS snippet (or some other plugin/tool that could generate source code) to have some of the boilerplate typed out for you, but at the end of the day that code will need to be there.